# moment date parsing in JS

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Using moment js

```
var y = moment('2016-01-11T16:00:00');
   console.log('UTC ' + moment().utc().format());
   console.log('Local ' + moment().format());
   console.log(y.format());
   console.log(y.toISOString());
```

Above code outputs

```
UTC 2016-07-12T19:54:15Z
Local 2016-07-12T15:54:15-04:00
2016-01-11T16:00:00-05:00
2016-01-11T21:00:00.000Z
```

Why it is displaying -05:00 offset in y.format().

Comment: Probably your timezone is -05:00.

Comment: Because you're not telling it what format you want, so it's giving you the default. See: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: @Gothdo it is -4:00 (EST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.format()` is designed to take a parameter that allows you to format the date exactly how you want to display it. Since you don't pass a parameter, it gives you the default, which in this case, shows the timezone (-05:00). Per the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/),

> As of version 1.5.0, calling moment#format without a format will
>   default to moment.defaultFormat. Out of the box, moment.defaultFormat
>   is the ISO8601 format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ`.
>
> As of version 2.13.0, when in UTC mode, the default format will return
>   Z as the offset, instead of +00:00.

Check the link for info about formatting a date with `.format()`.

Comment: I should have been more clear. When moment().format() prints 2016-07-12T15:54:15-04:00, I understand it defaults to ISO8601 but moment('2016-01-11T16:00:00').format() prints 2016-01-11T16:00:00-05:00 why it is -5 not -4 (It is EST -4 is correct offset). Does it mean it defaults to -5 offset always irrespective of local timezone? or does it not consider daylight saving in which -5 makes sense

Comment: did not notice it is JAN 11. so -5 makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

moment will default to ISO 8601 (Local time with offset to UTC), have a look a the documentation at [moment docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/), and more on the standard itself at [ISO 8601 Standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm)